# Jquery ui Datepicker maxDate dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Good Morning, 
I'd like to control dynamically the maxDate of my datepicker. For examp. : I have a date on my form on a textbox with value 20/12/12.

I tried this but is not working, the calendar is disabling the maxDate from the date i got on my textbox. Can you please help me with this:

```
$(function() { 
    var date = new Date(); 
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear(); 
    $("#Panel2nrFecha").datepicker({ 
        minDate: new Date(y, m, d), 
        maxDate: $("#Panel2nrTextBox1").val(), 
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/y", 
        defaultDate: "+1w", 
        changeMonth: true, 
        numberOfMonths: 3 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: $(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    $("#Panel2nrFecha").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(y, m, d),
    maxDate: $("#Panel2nrTextBox1").val(), 
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3
    
    });
});

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After you have initialized your datepicker, you can change the `maxDate` option like this:

```
$("#Panel2nrFecha").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $("#Panel2nrTextBox1").val() );
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `beforeShow` attribute of datepicker to set the minimum and maximum date, as outlined from this tutorial  [jQuery UI Datepicker v3.4.3 Examples - Date range](http://test.thecodecentral.com/cms/jqueryui/datepicker/#range) by Marc Grabanski and Keith Wood:

```
$("#Panel2nrFecha").datetimepicker({
    beforeShow: customRange,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/y", 
    defaultDate: "+1w", 
    changeMonth: true, 
    numberOfMonths: 3 
});

function customRange(input) {
    return { minDate: (input.id == 'Panel2nrMinDateTextBox' ? $('#Panel2nrMinDateTextBox').datepicker('getDate') : null),
        maxDate: (input.id == 'Panel2nrMaxDateTextBox' ? $('#Panel2nrMaxDateTextBox').datepicker('getDate') : null)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without posting some HTML, I'm not sure if this solves your issue, but did you try this:

```
$(function() { 
    var date = new Date();  
    $("#Panel2nrFecha").datepicker({ 
        minDate: date, 
        maxDate: new Date($("#Panel2nrTextBox1").val()), 
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/y", 
        defaultDate: "+1w", 
        changeMonth: true, 
        numberOfMonths: 3 
    }); 
});
```

Notice that I have removed the `y`,`m` and `d` variables, and also added `new Date()` on the `maxDate` property of the datepicker.