# Dynamically set maximum date in jquery (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

```
<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->

$(function() {

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: '-3M',
            maxDate: '+28D',
        });
    });
```

I want to give admin power so that they can dynamically set the maximum date from the drop down. For e.g - if admin selects 3 from drop down it should automatically reflect in maxDate.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343667/jquery-ui-datepicker-maxdate-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution

I added new dropdown where admin select value it will automatically add in MaxDate

```js
var newdate=$("#selected").val();
function getdate() {

console.log(newdate)
 $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: '-3M',
            maxDate: '+'+newdate+'D',
        });
    }
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("refresh");
    getdate() 
  function change(){
  newdate=$("#selected").val();
  getdate() 
  }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

<select id="selected" onchange="change()">
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: For 3 and 4 I can select upto 19th feb only. For 4 i need to select upto 20. But it is not working

Comment: you need to make datepicker in that way which it will select

my solution is for your above question you select value from dropdown and it will add in Max Date

Comment: Tried to set but it selects the first option only.

Comment: let me check please

Comment: The issue is still not solved. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Apratimduttachoudhury please check now. snippet is updated , now  working fine

Comment: if it work please accept answer  thank you